# Can We Style Inside A Const In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react , can i style inside a const

Here is my code

```
const initialStudentCounter =
    'Students' + ' ' +  JSON.stringify(studentCountInitial);
```

I need to style this "JSON.stringify(studentCountInitial)"

I tried this way , but didn't work

```
const initialStudentCounter =
    'Students' + ' ' +  <span style={color : 'red'}>JSON.stringify(studentCountInitial)</span> ;
```

Can some one help me please

Comment: Try to add double bracket to add css in reactJs. > style={{color : 'red'}}

Comment: thank for you comment @sedhalsoni , it return [OBJECT OBJECT]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `JSON.stringify` in JSX.  You do need to insert this into your JSX with a surrounding element.  You shouldn't need the `+` for concatenating strings anymore either.

```
export default function App() {
  const studentCountInitial = 4;
  const initialStudentCounter = <div>Students <span style={{color : 'red'}}>{studentCountInitial}</span></div>;

  return (
    initialStudentCounter
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, you need to use double curly brackets (The first set of brackets is telling the compiler that this is Javascript, the second set is telling the compiler that this is an object.) when styling elements. Also, surround your element with a string.

Code:

```
const initialStudentCounter =
    'Students' + ' ' + `<span style={{ color : 'red' }}>${JSON.stringify(studentCountInitial)}</span>`;
```

Comment: Saying it's "double brackets" misses the point.  The first set of brackets is telling the the compiler that this is JS, the second set is telling the compiler that this is an object.

Comment: @jmargolisvt added in answer

Comment: bro it return with the span tag

Comment: isn't that what you want?

Comment: no bro i am using this to print "initialStudentCounter"

Comment: it being passed to a tab view , where i get the number of count of the users, i need to style only the number

Comment: 'Students' + ' ' + `<span style={{ color : 'red' }}>${JSON.stringify(studentCountInitial)}</span>`; - number of count works but in view it return with the <span> tag

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems here:

- You're concatenating a string with a JSX element.
- Your `style` attribute's value is missing a pair of curly braces for opening and closing an object (the first pair merely lets you use JS syntax).

```
const initialStudentCounter = <p>Students <span style={{color : 'red'}}>{JSON.stringify(studentCountInitial)}</span></p>;
```

I also suspect that `studentCountInitial` is just a plain number and thus it probably doesn't need to be stringified. So you can probably just do this...

```
const initialStudentCounter = <p>Students <span style={{color : 'red'}}>{studentCountInitial}</span></p>;
```

If you really need to then convert that JSX element to a string, you could use something like [`ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostaticmarkup), but that's likely unnecessary.